# Fan out queries with multiple keys

Tags: influxdb

If I do

```
select * from s in to s.[key1].[key2]
```

And insert the point `{"key1": 0, "key2": 0}` into `s` then listing all series correctly shows 's.0.0'. However, I cannot query it. I get:

```
ERROR: Can't find series 's.0.0'
```

Even doing `select * from /.*/` fails with the same error until I delete 's.0.0'.

Can't I do fan out with more than one key at a time?

Comment: Ah, apparently InfluxDB doesn't deal well with empty json objects. Once I added another field to my point, everything worked fine.

Comment: You might want to file a bug, since this is not very intuitive behaviour, and post the link to it here as an answer.